# Grouping python dataframe by multiple column name

Tags: python, pandas

My goal in to split python dataframe by multiple columns. In the case of one column, data frame can be splitted by column 'X1' as below, using the groupby method. However, how to split dataframe according to columns X1 and X2?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X1': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'X2': ['Captive', 'Wild', 'Captive', 'Wild'],
                   'X3': ['BIG', 'SMALL', 'BIG', 'SMALL']})
dfs= dict(tuple(df.groupby('X1')))
dfs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If pass another column name is necessary select `dfs` by tuples:

```
dfs= dict(tuple(df.groupby(['X1', 'X2'])))

print (dfs[('Falcon','Captive')])
       X1       X2   X3
0  Falcon  Captive  BIG
```

If want select by `string`s is possible use `join` in dict comprehension:

```
dfs={f'{"_".join(k)}' : v for k, v in df.groupby(['X1', 'X2'])}
    
print (dfs['Falcon_Captive'])
       X1       X2   X3
0  Falcon  Captive  BIG
```